# How can I show php code in my single.php (wordpress) page based on category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope you could be able to help me with this problem that I have.
I want to put a newsletter box under article of my website (end of article) only in specific category that wordpress has (I have made some category).
I want put my code in single.php (wordpress) page and run the code only in specific category (for this case I want use tag_ID=425).
How can I do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  single.php is for a single post page. Are you saying you want code to run if a post is tagged with a given category?

Comment: Yes, I want to run the code only in specific category.